# Search an array of structs for a string variable

Tags: c++, visual-c++

consider:

```
const int CAP = 20;
struct bookType
{
    string bookTitle = "EMPTY";
    string ISBN = "EMPTY";
    string author = "EMPTY";
    string publisher = "EMPTY";
    string dateAdded = "EMPTY";
    int qty = 0;
    double wholesale = 0.00;
    double retail = 0.00;

};bookType book[CAP];
```

What I need to do here is hopefully simple, though I can't seem to get a straight answer on it. I want to search this array of structs (book[]) for a matching bookTitle. for instance, if I have a book named "Star Wars" I need to be able to search the array of structs by typing in "star" and finding a book, "Star Wars". I've been searching for hours, but all the solutions I've found don't seem to actually work.

Comment: Can you describe what you as a human would do in order to solve the task? Also, as new user here, please take the [tour] and read [ask]!

Comment: Do you know how to loop through your structs? Do you know how to do string substring comparisons that are case insensitive?

Comment: ***I've been searching for hours, but all the solutions I've found don't seem to actually work.*** Your professor did his / her homework meaning they want you to think about the problem instead of just using google to find a solution.

Comment: ***Can you describe what you as a human would do in order to solve the task?*** This is a good question. Since that is a solution to the problem. Do the same steps in `c++` code.

Comment: *though I can't seem to get a straight answer on it* -- The reason why you can't get a straight answer on it is that your program consists of multiple components -- looping, searching, string comparison, etc.  These are the components *you* need to put together in a logical way to come up with the final program.  Did you even put together a simple loop, just to loop through the array (forget about searching)?

Comment: You may want to place the member initializations into a *constructor* method.

Comment: Prefer to use `std::vector<bookType> library;` rather than arrays.  Arrays are fixed sized at compile time any may be too small or too large during runtime.  A `std::vector` can expand during runtime.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the rest of you code so I'll try to give a generic answer.

It seems like you are looking for the find() function for string objects. The find function will return std::string::npos if it does not find anything.

So inside a loop, test:

```
Booktype[x].bookTitle.find("Star")!=std::string::npos
```

Change Star to the whatever you are searching for. If this condition is true then you haave a match.

Just a heads up, this is case sensitive so you might want create temporary variables and convert the titles and queries into lowercases and run the loop on them.

Hope this helps.